# How can I move a object to another object center?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: move to center]

At the bottom the two same soldiers are childs of the female character so they are all move the same time.

What I want to do is to move the female character or any object even a cube to the center of the object in the top image the ShieldFX. I could add a empty gameobject on the ShieldFX and then destroy it when they are getting close to it but then again how do I know where to place the empty gameobject as center of the ShieldFX ?

I'm using in the Animator a HumanoidWalk animation for all the 3 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move an object towards to a transform create this script and attach it to the moving object:

```
public Transform targetObject;
private float speed;

void Update(){
  transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetObject.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Go to the object inspector, click "Add component", search for your script. Then, the script will appear in the inspector. Drag your target object (the ShieldFX) to fill the field called "TargetObject". And that's it!
Hoping to have answered your question.
Bye!